# How do I read a big SQL query string from a file?

Tags: iphone, sql, xcode, sqlite, nsstring

I'm writing a database project on the iPhone and I'd like to store some big SQL queries in a separate, project-included file.

Then, I'd like to read this query into an NSString * (or, well, const char * is also ok) reference, and then perform it with an sqlite3.

I'm a newbie to iPhone developing, and I have never worked with files, neither I know any details of their storage.

Could you please give me a hint on:

1. The appropriate file format to store the strings.
2. How do I store it into the iPhone;
3. How do I read from it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

1. Any simple character based (text) file would be more than enough
2. Just put it in a folder in your project, it will get deployed with your Application
3. Use `NSString` class.

For issue #3 you can use:

```
NSString *sqlString = 
   [NSString 
      stringWithContentsOfFile:@"yourqueryfile.sql" 
      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
      errors:nil //unless yuo are interested in errors.
   ];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I shall try that.